# Jekyll Highlight Tag: Prevent escaping

Tags: jekyll, highlighting

```
{% highlight %}
I want {% raw %}<span class="handle">{% endraw %}this span{% raw %}</span>{% endraw %} to be rendered as HTML.
{% endhighlight %}
```

Is it possible to prevent Jekyll's `highlight` tag from processing some parts of the input?

In the above example, I would like Jekyll to produce HTML like this:

```
<pre>
  <code>I want <span class="handle">this span</span> to be rendered in HTML</code>
</pre>
```

, rather than:

```
<pre>
  <code>I want &lt;span class="handle" ...</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Any other example? Why not just write `<pre>
  <code>I want <span class="handle">this span</span> to be rendered in HTML</code>
</pre>`?

Comment: Well, then I can't use {% highlight linenos %}. With linenos, the HTML markup gets quite complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlight tag take two argument. First argument is the language you need to highlight(I assume it html) and second argument is called `linenos` that is an optional which will enforce the highlighted code to include line numbers.So you need to use html to get what you want.

```
{% highlight html %}
I want {% raw %}<span class="handle">{% endraw %}this span{% raw %}</span>{% endraw %} to be rendered as HTML.
{% endhighlight %}
```

In other words, you can't use `{% highlight %}` for that. Fall back on HTML, if it isn't too verbose.

HTML's verbosity can be solved by Jekyll's `{% include %}`.

## Jekyll is powerful and flexible.

Using `{% include %}` to include snippets can lend well to concise expressions.

The include:

```
{% assign linenos = "1 2 3" | split: " " %}
{% include linenos.html numbers=linenos %}
{% highlight text %}
Once upon a time, there was a unicorn.

The unicorn looked around.
{% endhighlight %}
```

The included snippet:

```
<pre class="linenos"><code>{% for number in include.numbers %}{{ number }}
{% endfor %}</code></pre>
```

And the accompanying CSS is simply: `pre.linenos { float: left; }`

The result is *the ability to add line numbers (via `{% include %}`)*, in your preferred style, no less.
The above "*unicorn*" example is seen [here](https://jon-wong-sutd.github.io/git-lessons/git-lesson/#working-copy-of-project-files).

A more involved example you would want is where you can add `<span>` elements inside. You need to ditch `{% highlight %}` and go with `<pre><code></code></pre>` yourself, sorry. **Jekyll's `{% highlight %}` escapes all content it receives, no exception.** That example is [here](https://jon-wong-sutd.github.io/git-lessons/git-lesson/#anatomy-of-a-commit).

## Plugins can work too

But not if you're publishing directly (no `jekyll build` step of your own) to GitHub Pages.

If you include your own scripts to do `jekyll build` (like what is done in above-mentioned project), feel free to write your own plugins!

Comment: @{Abdul Hadi} You're right. After some searching, I've resorted to HTML. Can you please add my answer to yours, so that I can mark yours as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

@{Abdul Hadi}

Can you please add my answer here to yours? You're the first to answer me correctly, and I want to mark your answer as correct.

My answer...

Short answer, you can't use `{% highlight %}` for that. Fall back on HTML, if it isn't too verbose.

HTML's verbosity can be solved by Jekyll's `{% include %}`.

## Jekyll is powerful and flexible.

Using `{% include %}` to include snippets can lend well to concise expressions.

The include:

```
{% assign linenos = "1 2 3" | split: " " %}
{% include linenos.html numbers=linenos %}
{% highlight text %}
Once upon a time, there was a unicorn.

The unicorn looked around.
{% endhighlight %}
```

The included snippet:

```
<pre class="linenos"><code>{% for number in include.numbers %}{{ number }}
{% endfor %}</code></pre>
```

And the accompanying CSS is simply: `pre.linenos { float: left; }`

The result is *the ability to add line numbers (via `{% include %}`)*, in your preferred style, no less.
The above "*unicorn*" example is seen [here](https://jon-wong-sutd.github.io/git-lessons/git-lesson/#working-copy-of-project-files).

A more involved example you would want is where you can add `<span>` elements inside. You need to ditch `{% highlight %}` and go with `<pre><code></code></pre>` yourself, sorry. **Jekyll's `{% highlight %}` escapes all content it receives, no exception.** That example is [here](https://jon-wong-sutd.github.io/git-lessons/git-lesson/#anatomy-of-a-commit).

## Plugins can work too

But not if you're publishing directly (no `jekyll build` step of your own) to GitHub Pages.

If you include your own scripts to do `jekyll build` (like what is done in above-mentioned project), feel free to write your own plugins!